# Unable to figure out why the solution to a quadratic inequality works

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x(2x+7)\ge 0$$

I solved this inequality a few days ago and I was referencing it to complete other ones just now and am at a loss for how I came up the with solution.

$$(-\infty ,-\frac { 7 }{ 2 } )\quad \bigcup  \quad [0,\infty )$$

I factored it. Came up with:

$$(x+\frac { 7 }{ 2 } )(x+0)$$

Now I must use test values to see which intervals satisfy the inequality. But when I enter something like:

$$-5+\frac { 7 }{ 2 } $$

It doesn't satisfy the solution set. I know that I must be doing something really wrong here. I am just not able to pinpoint it at the moment for some reason that is beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x-a)(x-b)\ge0$ where $a<b$

If $x-a>0,$ we need $x-b\ge0\implies x\ge b$

If $x-a\le 0,$ we need $x-b<0\implies x\le a$

Comment: So if the graphed solution set saids that anything less than $$-\frac { 7 }{ 2 } $$ is part of the solution, why isn't -5 working?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, $$-5(2\cdot-5+7)=(-5)(-3)>0$$

Comment: -5+(7/2) gives me a number less than 0

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, How $$+\frac72$$ is coming

Comment: Because x+7/2 = 0

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, We need the product to be $\ge0$

Comment: None of this is making sense to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16684/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-cherry-developer).